# Refactoring jQuery show/hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of divs I would like to show and hide based on links that a user can click. Is there a way to refactor these functions to be less repetitive?

Possibly using toggle?

```
$('#section1').hide();
$('#section2').hide();
$('#section3').hide();
$('#section4').hide();

$('#section1-link').click(function () {
    $('#section1').show();
    $('#section2').hide();
    $('#section3').hide();
    $('#section4').hide();
});
$('#section2-link').click(function () {
    $('#section1').hide();
    $('#section2').show();
    $('#section3').hide();
    $('#section4').hide();
});
$('#section3-link').click(function () {
    $('#section1').hide();
    $('#section2').hide();
    $('#section3').show();
    $('#section4').hide();
});
$('#section4-link').click(function () {
    $('#section1').hide();
    $('#section2').hide();
    $('#section3').hide();
    $('#section4').show();
});
```

Comment: Yes, use common classes instead.

Comment: yes, just call .click to bind the events once. No need to do that 4 times.

Comment: @KevinB But the code for each one is different.

Comment: @KevinB he is using a different code for each click condition

Comment: @Barmar only slightly, the difference can be coded in a more dynamic way (i think you know that)

Comment: @KevinB And that's what he's asking how to do.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/hisomoq/2/edit?css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/a5wh7ogc/2/)**.

I suggest the use of common classes with the help of `data-*`, check the example below.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.section-link').on('click', function(){
    var section_id = '#'+ $(this).data('section');

    $('.section').hide(); //Hide all sections
    $(section_id).show(); //Show the related one
})
```

```css
div:not(#section1){
  display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' class='section-link' data-section='section1'>Link 1</a>
<a href='#' class='section-link' data-section='section2'>Link 2</a>
<a href='#' class='section-link' data-section='section3'>Link 3</a>
<a href='#' class='section-link' data-section='section4'>Link 4</a>

<div class='section' id='section1'>Section 1</div>
<div class='section' id='section2'>Section 2</div>
<div class='section' id='section3'>Section 3</div>
<div class='section' id='section4'>Section 4</div>
```